# Triton Inference Server - tritonserver: not found

Tags: triton, tritonserver

I try to run NVIDIA’s Triton Inference Server. I pulled the pre-built container nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.06-py3 and then run it with the command

```
run --gpus=1 --rm -p8000:8000 -p8001:8001 -p8002:8002 -v/F/models:/models nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.06-py3 tritonserver --model-repository=/models
```

and got the error

```
/opt/nvidia/nvidia_entrypoint.sh: line 49: exec: tritonserver: not found
```

I googled and have not found something to catch this.
I tried to change tritonserver to trtserver as recommended but it did not help.
Please give some advice how it can be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to run a `tritonserver` using a `pytorch` image but [according to the **triton-server quick start guide**](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server/blob/main/docs/quickstart.md#run-triton), the image should be:

```
$ docker run --gpus=1 --rm -p8000:8000 -p8001:8001 -p8002:8002 -v/full/path/to/docs/examples/model_repository:/models nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:<xx.yy>-py3 tritonserver --model-repository=/models
```

*Where <xx.yy> is the version of Triton that you want to use*

In your case it should be `nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:22.06-py3`
and the full command:

```
run --gpus=1 --rm -p8000:8000 -p8001:8001 -p8002:8002 -v/F/models:/models nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:22.06-py3 tritonserver --model-repository=/models
```